# Prevent scroll bar movement after first click on filename under edge of window (screenshots included)

Tags: windows-7, gui

I just installed Windows 7, and there’s something that’s bugging me.

In the first picture before the first click:
[image]

To open 73, I’d usually just double-click, or use a remapped keyboard button that executes 2 clicks.  However, since it’s on the edge (not in full view), when I click once the scroll bar moves right (helps get 73 centered?).

In the second picture, after the single click that shifts the scroll bar right:
[image]

I can’t double click because the first click shifts it.

Can I stop the scroll bar movement?

Thanks for any help or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot stop the scroll bar from being adjusted automatically.  This is a feature of the GUI where there is an attempt to place the whole item in view (or at least as much of it as possible if it's too large to fit the viewport).

This is particularly important because if an item is outside the viewable area of the window, then it's possible for a user to rename it (or perform some other potentially destructive operation on it such as "Delete") without realizing that they did so.

Comment: You can gain a little extra space by turning off your Navigation Pane on the left-hand side (maybe this will help a little bit?):  Organize -> Layout -> Navigation pane

Comment: Whoa sweet! Didn't know about that. Thanks